# How to tie an objects lifetime to another objects lifetime with C#

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Assume you have an .net object `bufferObject` that uses some kind of unmanaged memory buffer of considerable size internally. It is implemented in a way that it will free its allocated memory when disposed (or finalized).

You then create a different object `reusingBufferObject` and supply it with a pointer to the **internal buffer** of `bufferObject`. So the two objects themselves don't know about each others existence.

If `bufferObject` goes out of scope and is disposed/finalized, the internal buffer will be freed and `reusingBufferObject` will access invalid memory.

Of course the whole problem can be avoided by changing the design of the underlying classed of the two objects and letting `reusingBufferObject` reference `bufferObject`. But let's assume that both objects are instantiated of third party classes and their design cannot be changed.

An example case would be the use of some image processing library. An internal image object would have to be converted to a `Bitmap` object to display it onscreen, but for performance reasons the image objects internal buffer has to be reused by the `Bitmap` object, instead of just being copied to it.

Is it possible to tie the lifetime of `bufferObject` to the lifetime of `reusingBufferObject`, so that it gets eligible for garbage collection only after `reusingBufferObject` does, without keeping track of the lifetime manually?

**EDIT:**

Here a quick example to illustrate the problem:

```
namespace Example
{
    // Some third party class with no control over its design.
    // The Data property is the pointer to an unmanaged memory
    // buffer.
    public class ThirdPartyImage : IDisposable
    {
        public int Width { get; }
        public int Height { get; }
        public int Stride { get; }
        public PixelFormat Format { get; }
        public IntPtr Data { get; }

        public ThirdPartyImage(string filename);
        public Dispose();
    }

    public static class MyOwnExtensions
    {
        // Some method to reuse the internal memory buffer.
        public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this ThirdPartyImage image)
        {
            return new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, image.Stride, image.Format,
                image.Data);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = Foo();

            // ThirdPartyImage is not referenced anymore and the internal buffer (Data)
            // will be freed when garbage collected.

            Bar(bitmap);
        }

        private static Bitmap Foo()
        {
            ThirdPartyImage image = ThirdPartyImage("foo.bmp");
            Bitmap bitmap = image.ToBitmap();

            return bitmap;
        }

        private static void Bar(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            // Do some Bitmap related work here.
            // The buffer could already be freed though.
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

What I am looking for is something like a garbage collection method, that lets you tie an objects lifetime to another one.

Or some kind of notification when the `reusingBufferObject` / `Bitmap` is being collected or getting eligible for collection, so that I can build some automated mechanism involving a helper object that holds a strong reference to `bufferObject` and a `WeakReference` to `reusingBufferObject`.

Manually keeping track of two objects of which one is actually not needed anymore (except for its internally used buffer), for example by introducing a wrapper class, just seems to be overly complicated to me.

Comment: It depends on what class `bufferObject` derives from. Also, can you provide more details about the types involved in general? The metadata view of the types for `bufferObject` and `reusingBufferObject` would be very useful.

Comment: It is not possible to answer this question without more details. The exact semantics of how the various objects are allocated and destroyed determines if this can be done or not.

Comment: Even if `bufferObject` is not collected before `reusingBufferObject` how you are planning to prevent `bufferObject.Dispose()` call?

Comment: I am basically letting `bufferObject` run out of scope. I edited my answer with a small example to illustrate my point.

Comment: In your case (after your edit) you must keep `ThirdPartyImage` alive by holding a reference to it along with the bitmap - you could do this by using a class that holds both so you always pass both of them around as much as you can. Alternatively, you need to copy the buffer if you need to release the 3-rd party object.

Comment: @xxbbcc: As stated in my question, I do not want to copy the buffer and I do not want to manually keep track of the lifetime.

Comment: @LaurentsC.R.Meyer You have no choice - `Bitmap` itself implements `IDisposable` and you have to manually clean it up when you're done with it anyway. At some point, you'll have to manually clean up at least one object - you might as well just put these in a class that holds them and deal with it.

Comment: @LaurentsC.R.Meyer I'm curious: why do you want to avoid just dealing with the problem (that's otherwise not very complicated)?

Comment: Okay, I think I found the solution:
Using ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>.

Comment: @xxbbcc
The reason why I am reluctant to manually deal with the situation is, that if you consider the Bitmap problem above, the application would need to keep track of every bitmap and if it is responsible for its own memory management or not. Encapsulating all Bitmap objects into a wrapper class is of course possible. But since this is merely a performance optimization and introducing a wrapper class would imply some considerable refactoring, I am not very keen to use this approach.

Comment: @LaurentsC.R.Meyer Thank you for the explanation. I don't want to get into a long chat (or convince you otherwise) but I do want to point out that if you have an existing application that you change to use a new 3rd-party library, it's not just performance optimization - you're changing semantics of your objects. You may be better off biting the bullet and refactor it. Just my two cents. :)

Comment: @xxbbcc I agree. I my case, I have been using the library the whole time. The application is basically feature complete, so I am just optimizing the hell out of it now. Because this is basically a fire and forget scenario here, I am fine with my solution. Though the proper/clean way of doing this would be to manually track the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, it seems that [ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx) is doing what I want.
By changing the example a little bit, it should work:

```
public static class MyOwnExtensions
{
    private static readonly ConditionalWeakTable<Bitmap, ThirdPartyImage>
        WeakBitmapImageTable = new ConditionalWeakTable<Bitmap, ThirdPartyImage>();

    public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this ThirdPartyImage image)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, image.Stride, image.Format,
            image.Data);
        WeakBitmapImageTable.Add(bitmap, image);

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whoever creates the object is responsible for disposing them. If you have `objectA` and `objectA` needs `objectB` but both objects are created by a third object `objectC`, then `objectC` needs to make sure to dispose both of them.

That is the most important point to remember: **The creator is responsible for disposal**.

This is one of the biggest issues with some IoC containers: they create things but when it comes to disposal, things are left to someone else and that makes things pretty tricky.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question is very generic and it cannot be answered as is. My answer only attempts to answer your specific code example in the question.

Since `ThirdPartyImage` implements `IDisposable`, its expected behavior is that it keeps that buffer until you call `Dispose()` on it. If you don't want to make a copy of the image buffer, you must keep a reference to `ThirdPartyImage` for the entire lifetime of your bitmap, otherwise your program will crash at some point when the buffer gets freed up and the bitmap fails to render.

You can do this in multiple ways - using a global map of `ThirdPartyImage` instances, keyed by the bitmap (this is tricky and can become a maintenance problem quickly) or you can keep both objects (`ThirdPartyImage` and the bitmap) in a class that you pass around to every place (that you can). This way, when you're ready to get rid of the bitmap, you just destroy the holder object which will call `Dispose()` on both the bitmap and then on `ThirdPartyImage`.

You can try coming up with ways to hide this sort of setup deeper in some structure that seemingly automates this but at the end one object reaches inside another and this ties them together. Only you know when it's safe to get rid of the first object so that the second object can also go away.